# Disable inheritance and manually apply permissions when creating a folder in Powershell

Tags: powershell, inheritance

Im trying to make a new folder in Powershell but I do not want it to inherit any NTFS security permissions and manually add 2 users: The creator and my own admin account.

I have this:

```
    $FolderPath = "\\srv\path"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $FolderPath
$acl = Get-Acl "\\srv\path"
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
$acl.Access | %{$acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)} # I remove all security
$acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] $env:USERNAME) # I set the current user as owner
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('myadminaccount','FullControl','Allow') # I set my admin account as also having access
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $FolderPath $acl | Out-Null
```

It does not work and it sill inherits the parent's security permissions.

I changed it to the comment below but it does not allow the user to set ACLs for a folder HE created. Over the root folder (path), he has change permissions privileges...

This is the access error recieved

[image]

What permissions should he have over the folder he just created with the code above? The owner should be able to modify it freely.

Added the full control share permission for the user and now I get that the process does not have "SeSecurityPrivilege". This happens when I add the $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False) line

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`SetAccessRuleProtection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y5xz70d(v=vs.110).aspx) method to exclude the ACL from inheriting rules:

```
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)
```

The second argument (`preserveInheritance`) also removes existing inherited rules when set to `false`, leaving just the system default ACE's.

---

If you have problems applying the inheritance protection, make sure you update the ACL with the ownership information before setting access rule protection:

```
$acl = Get-Acl "\\srv\path"
# SetOwner
$acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] $env:USERNAME)
# Write updated ownership info back
Set-Acl $FolderPath $acl | Out-Null
# SetAccessRuleProtection
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
# Write updated ACL back
Set-Acl $FolderPath $acl | Out-Null
```

Comment: It does not allow the user to remove ACL. The user has "Change permissions" over the folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are unrelated. `SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)` does what is documented: Removes inherited ACEs and protects against inheriting future parent ACEs

Comment: I just added a screenshot to make sure if it is related or not.

Comment: @riahc3 Make sure you (the executing user) has Full Control permissions on the Share as well

Comment: He has all the permissions except that one; Full Control. Does he really need Full Controll?

Comment: @riahc3 I'm not talking about the NTFS permission, but the *share* permissions

Comment: OK, gotcha. Added the Full Control share permission and now I do have another error....Looking at it as I speak.

Comment: Now I am getting that the process does not have "SeSecurityPrivilege". This happens when I add the $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False) line

Comment: That's because the user isn't a member of the Administrators group on the target server. TBH you should probably ask a new/separate question for this

Comment: No, he isnt but he shouldnt be either in order to write the that specific folder. Should I change order the code in my script for it to work?

Comment: @riahc3 Yes, apply the ownership first, then call `SetAccessRuleProtection` subsequently, that might work

Comment: Changing the order did it I believe. I would love to mark your answer as correct but it doesn't have the complete answer. I did upload your comment.

Answer (score 7):

The error about 'SeSecurityPrivilege' is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/789418/unable-to-set-acl-using-set-acl-when-not-admin-on-acl-protected-folder) with Set-Acl for file system objects. I'd recommend against using Set-Acl for files and folders, and instead use the SetAccessControl() method that's available for file and folder objects. You could modify your code to look like this:

```
$FolderPath = "\\srv\path"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $FolderPath
$acl = Get-Acl $FolderPath
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
$acl.Access | % { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) } # I remove all security
# Not needed:
# $acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] $env:USERNAME) # I set the current user as owner
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('myadminaccount', 'FullControl', 'Allow') # I set my admin account as also having access
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
(Get-Item $FolderPath).SetAccessControl($acl)
```

One more thing: you might want to change your $rule to something like the following if it's going to apply to a folder:

```
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    'myadminaccount',
    'FullControl',
    'ObjectInherit, ContainerInherit',
    'None',
    'Allow'
)
```